# Inserting a dash (-) when a value is missing

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

How do I get a '-' to appear on my calendar whenever the value for a day of week is empty?

Here is the code:

```
 public static void printCalander(int month, int year) {
    String[] monthNames = {"", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    //showing which month is being displayed on the yearly calendar
    System.out.println("    " + monthNames[month] + " " + year);
    System.out.println("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa");
    for (int index = 0; index < obj1; index++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    //numDays is showing how many days are needed for the calendar following the user input
    for (int count = 1; count <= numDays; count++) { 
        System.out.printf("%2d ", count);

        //if the calendar reaches 7 numbers then it will take a new line 
        if (((count + obj1) % 7 == 0) || (count == numDays)) { 
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }//for
}//end of printCalendar
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly u need to make an integer array for week days and use it like a controller like this:

```
String[] array = new String[7];

//take inputs like this:
for(int i = 0; i<7; i++) {
    input = k.nextLine();
    if(input.equals(""))
        array[i] = "-";
        continue;
    }
    array[i] = input;
}
```

or save inputs in a array and control it. if it has a null element change it to "-".